# Exception when trying to obtain a reference to the native COM object of the SwapChainPanel in Windows App SDK C# using SharpDX and DXD11

Tags: c#, xaml, directx, vsix, sharpdx

I am trying to obtain a reference to the native COM object of the SwapChainPanel created in Windows App SDK C# using SharpDX.

I migrated my project from UWP to the newer Windows App SDK with WinUI 3 and .Net 6 and everything works except the creation of the SwapChainPael.

UWP:
https://github.com/CanTalat-Yakan/UWP-GameEngineEditor/blob/main/Editor/Views/View_Port.xaml.cs
https://github.com/CanTalat-Yakan/UWP-GameEngineEditor/blob/main/Editor/Assets/Engine/Utilities/Engine_Renderer.cs

New Windows App SDK:
https://github.com/CanTalat-Yakan/3D_Engine-WinUI3/blob/main/WinUI3DEngine/WinUI3DEngine/WinUI3DEngine/UserControls/ViewPort.xaml.cs
https://github.com/CanTalat-Yakan/3D_Engine-WinUI3/blob/main/WinUI3DEngine/WinUI3DEngine/WinUI3DEngine/Assets/Engine/Utilities/CRenderer.cs

The part with said Error is this CRenderer:71(ctor)

```
        // Obtain a reference to the native COM object of the SwapChainPanel.
        using (var nativeObject = ComObject.As<DXGI.ISwapChainPanelNative2>(m_SwapChainPanel))
            nativeObject.SwapChain = m_SwapChain;
```

Exception Details:

> SharpDX.SharpDXException   HResult=0x80004002   Message=HRESULT:
> [0x80004002], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_NOINTERFACE/No such
> interface supported], Message: No such interface supported
>
> Source=SharpDX   StackTrace:    at SharpDX.Result.CheckError()    at
> SharpDX.ComObject.QueryInterface(Guid guid, IntPtr& outPtr)    at
> SharpDX.ComObject.QueryInterfaceT    at
> SharpDX.ComObject.As[T](Object comObject)    at
> WinUI3DEngine.Assets.Engine.Utilities.CRenderer..ctor(SwapChainPanel
> _swapChainPanel) in D:\Misc\Sourcetree\Engine\WinUI3DEngine\WinUI3DEngine\WinUI3DEngine\Assets\Engine\Utilities\CRenderer.cs:line
> 71    at WinUI3DEngine.Assets.Engine.CEngine..ctor(SwapChainPanel
> _swapChainPanel, TextBlock _textBlock) in D:\Misc\Sourcetree\Engine\WinUI3DEngine\WinUI3DEngine\WinUI3DEngine\Assets\Engine\CEngine.cs:line
> 18    at WinUI3DEngine.UserControls.ViewPort.Initialize(Object sender,
> RoutedEventArgs e) in
> D:\Misc\Sourcetree\Engine\WinUI3DEngine\WinUI3DEngine\WinUI3DEngine\UserControls\ViewPort.xaml.cs:line
> 41    at
> WinRT._EventSource_global__Microsoft_UI_Xaml_RoutedEventHandler.EventState.b__1_0(Object
> sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    at
> ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Do_Abi_Invoke>b__0(RoutedEventHandler
> invoke)    at WinRT.ComWrappersSupport.MarshalDelegateInvoke[T](IntPtr
> thisPtr, Action`1 invoke)    at
> ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler.Do_Abi_Invoke(IntPtr thisPtr,
> IntPtr sender, IntPtr e)

I tried debuging from the beginning of the process and everthing is similar to the UWP version. With the new Windows App SDK the namespace of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls changed to Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls
I don't know much about the SharpDX wrapper, but could that be the problem?
Maybe SharpDX simply doesn't support .Net 5 or 6 only 4 and below?
Do I need to setup the creation of the Device -Contex and lastly the SwapchainPanel differently?

If I get a solution, if it was my mistake or another, I will post them here below

Comment: Probably not telling you anything you don't already know but going by the error and code, looks like whatever the object is behind `m_SwapChainPanel` doesn't implement the `ISwapChainPanelNative2` interface?  Is it absolutely necessary to use the newer COM library? The thing about native code is that you shouldn't upgrade just for the sake of it

Comment: Do you have a simple reproducing project (not a big one)?

Comment: Done. Here is a simple reproduction of the Exception: https://github.com/CanTalat-Yakan/SimpleReproduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically

windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop::ISwapChainPanelNative which works with the UWP Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel control

doesnt work with the

WinUI3 Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel control, which implements a different interface which has the same name but a new GUID (63aad0b8-7c24-40ff-85a8-640d944cc325) and namespace: microsoft.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop::ISwapChainPanelNative

Notice the namespace difference of Windows vs Microsoft
https://githubhot.com/repo/amerkoleci/Vortice.Windows/issues/91

here would be a workaround:
https://github.com/amerkoleci/Vortice.Windows/discussions/164

but as SharpDX is depracted, I switched to an updated wrapper Vortice
https://github.com/amerkoleci/Vortice.Windows
https://github.com/amerkoleci/Vortice.Windows/tree/main/src

which supports the WinUI 3  and the new Windows App SDK (new project reunion)